# How to allow CORS from Axios get request in Django backend?

Tags: python, django, rest, axios, cors

I've been looking for a solution to this problem but nothing seems to work. I've arrived at the [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers) package but can't get it to work.

I'm sending an `axios` request form my `vue` frontend:

```
axios.get('data/')
    .then(res => { console.log(res) })
```

but it throws a `200 network error` error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/data/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

- 

```
GET http://localhost:8000/data/ net::ERR_FAILED 200
```

- 

```
AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_NETWORK"
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
: 
"Network Error"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: true, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
stack
: 
"AxiosError: Network Error\n
```

#### Django backend

I am redirecting the incoming request in **`myProject/urls.py`**:

```
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myApp.urls')),
]
```

to **`myApp/urls.py`**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('data/', views.getData)
]
```

which invokes **`myApp/views.py`**:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from base.models import Item
from .serializers import ItemSerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
def getData(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    serializer = ItemSerializer(items, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

with **`base/models.py`**:

```
from django.db import models


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and **`myApp/serializers.py`**:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from base.models import Item


class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

I've installed the `django-cors-headers` package and configured it in **`myProject/settings.py`**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
]
```

with either:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
```

or

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

but none of both works. I've tried reading up on the [package docs](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers) but can't find the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it throws a 200 network error error

There's no such thing as a "200 network error": if you got a 200 status code, there was no problem with the network, since the browser did receive a response from the server. Instead, what happens is that the CORS check failed, for some reason; as a result, the browser denied your client access to the response and raised a CORS error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/data/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

If you're getting such an error message, it's because

- your client code is sending a credentialed request, but
- your server's CORS configuration doesn't allow such requests.

Your question doesn't show it but I suspect you have configured your Axios client to always send requests with credentials. However, setting `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` in your CORS config without also setting `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` [results](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers/blob/e3baf99bbade71da5b7dd905f70f52b2a3844494/src/corsheaders/middleware.py#LL156C11-L156C11) in the following response header,

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

and [the wildcard happens to be incompatible with credentialed requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards). If you want to allow credentialed requests, you need to also set the following in your CORS configuration:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Otherwise, instruct your Axios client not to send credentialed requests.

Comment: Wow, you are absolutely right. I had a `axios.js` setup file which had `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true`. I've removed it and now the response is sent correctly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov 

Comment: Just a small remark, setting `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` with `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS ` doesn't seem to work. Instead I have to set origins with `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [...]` and also allow credentials. Then it works.